# How do I create a route for matching all paths starting with a given prefix?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my MVC application I want to create a route such that when a user requests a URL starting with a prefix some specific action is invoked.

For example, I want a route that would map `processData{whatever}` onto an action so that when a user requests `processData`, `processData.asmx` or `processDataZOMG` or whatever else with `processData` prefix that action is invoked.

I tried the following route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    @"ProcessData", @"processData*", //<<<< note asterisk
    new { controller = @"Api", action = @"ProcessData" } );
```

but it doesn't match `processData` and anything with that prefix - route matching falls through and the request is redirected to the main page.

How do I make a route that matches all paths with a specific prefix onto a specific controller-action pair?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try the following:</s> ***Update***: This solution does not work, please refer to the solution I offer in my comment to this answer.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    @"ProcessData", @"processData/{*appendix}", //<<<< note asterisk
    new { controller = @"Api", action = @"ProcessData" } );
```

Comment: This doesn't match `processDataX`.

Comment: You're right. You can, however, implement a custom `IRouteHandler` that checks if the part behind the last slash (given you trim trailing slashes) starts with "processData".

Answer (score 0):

You could use route constraints:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProcessData", // Route name
    "{token}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Api", action = "ProcessData" }, // Parameter defaults
    new { token = @"^processdata.*" } // constraints
);
```